# Two dice are thrown together. What is the probability of showing an odd number on either die and a multiple of 3 on the other?

Tags: probability

> Two dice are thrown together. What is the probability of showing an odd number on either die and a multiple of 3 on the other?

Is the answer just $\frac12×\frac13×2$?

Comment: Notice that someone has edited your "question" (which was originally just a statement) to make it actually be a question. If the new question is not what you intended, I suggest you edit it again, but please make it a question and don't make people guess what you want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability for an odd number on *the first die* and a multiple of 3 on *the second* is indeed $\frac16$. However, multiplying by two does not give the correct answer because it counts the case where *both dice* show odd multiples of 3 – a "hard six" of two threes, in craps jargon – twice.

The correct answer is $2×\frac16-\frac1{36}=\frac{11}{36}$.